# Ninject: How to resolve Kernel itself/this?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, ninject

Here is module:

```
public class InjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<DbContext>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<ISomeRepository>().To<SomeRepository>()
            .InThreadScope();
        Bind<MainWindow>().ToSelf().InThreadScope();
        Bind<IKernel>() //how to bind???
    }
}
```

my app:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{         
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new InjectModule());
    MainWindow window = kernel.Get<MainWindow>();
    window.Show();
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

I need kernel as property `DependencyResolver` in main window. how to make it works?

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    [Inject]
    public IKernel DependencyResolver { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why you have to inject IKernel itself? you are creating a *super factory* for your class which is not a good pratice

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: wrong typo, correct :)

Comment: @CuongLe How can i bind to itselt? i don't know how to do it

Comment: oh, i get it, i don't need any bind. it resolves it selt, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use the kernel directly outside a module. The kernel itself has automatic module loading which scans for ninject modules in your base directory if you want it to do so. If a component needs to resolve a specific instance you should use the provided extensions like the factory extension which allows to inject Func, Lazy or dynamic factories according to a interface. If any of the extensions don't help then inject the IResolutionRoot interface but never IKernel!

Comment: could u post an example?

Comment: Of course if you describe a bit more what you want to achieve